# Do precompiled headers speed up compilation if there is only one `.c` file that includes them?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header, precompiled-headers

My understanding of [precompiled headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-160) is as follows:

We create the `stdafx.h` file:

```
#pragma once
#include <code1.h>
#include <code2.h>
...
#include <codeN.h>
```

And the `stdafx.cc` file:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

Now if each of the multiple `main1.c`, `main2.c`, `main3.c` files include the `stdafx.h` header, then when you compile the `main1.c` for the first time, everything that the `stdafx.h` includes will be parsed and compiled into an object file, but compiling the next `main2.c` and `main3.c` files will not require to parse the `stdafx.h` file again.

However, suppose I only have a `main1.c` file and no `main2.c` or `main3.c` files. Would using a precompiled header offer any improvements than just including `codeX.h` into the `main.c` directly?

Comment: Is there such a thing as precompiled headers?  Headers generally don't have code that can be compiled, right?

Comment: Easy enough to test. Might save you time on incremental compiles, might not. Even on large projects it may not be the right way to go.

Comment: @FiddlingBits • [precompiled headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-160) are a thing.  Supported by many compilers.  They have pros & cons, and when used they are sometimes misused and make incremental compile times take longer than if they weren't used at all.

Comment: @Eljay: Can confirm, have used them a lot in the past. It's an art more than a science IMO. Sometimes have eventually gotten rid of them altogether. Probably will fade into oblivion as module adoption increases.

Comment: If you compile that single translation unit multiple times, you get the same "benefit" as if there are multiple translation units.

Comment: @WilliamPursell but If I compile the same project twice with `Make`, the second time `make` skips the compilation regardless of whether I use precompiled headers or not. So what's the benefit here?

Comment: @mercury0114 Not if you've modified the timestamp on the .c file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you mean the timestamp of `main1.c`? Suppose `main1.c` needs to be recompiled. Either it uses `#include<stdafx.h>` and does not recompile `stdafx.c` because nothing has changed there, or it uses `#include<code1.h>`, `#include<code2.h>`, `#include<code3.h>` and does not recompile any of `code1.c`, `code2.c`, `code3.c` for the same reason. Still I don't see an improvement

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems that if `main1.c` is being recompiled and includes `<stdafx.h>` but does not need to recompile `stdafx.h` because that header has been precompiled, that is the difference that the precompiled header provides.

Comment: Precompiled headers help if you have many standard library and third party includes. If you have a small program that does not include many files it won't help. You generally don't include own files in the precompiled header unless these are headers from your project that you don't expect to change.

Comment: In Visual Studio I have pch files in some projects that are 100s of MB in size (using boost + ITK + VTK + GDCM + Qt). It can help quite a bit in this scenario provided you don't add things to the pch often and avoid changing the headers that are in the pch.

Comment: @WilliamPursell hmm, so it seems that this `stdafx.h` header is a special header, that unlike other headers can be precompiled... And then I guess you need special tools to distinguish it, a simple `make` command without any special flags probably won't notice the difference of this header.

Answer (score 2):

> Do precompiled headers speed up compilation if there is only one `.c` file that includes them?

Potentially yes, assuming you are using a previously pre-compiled header.

Comment: And that none of the header files in the precompiled header are changed.

Comment: Does it mean that in this case the header file `stdafx.h` is somehow special and compiler treats it differently than other header files? Because if not, I don't see why `#include <stdafx.h>` gives rise to a "precompiled header" whereas `#include<another_file.h>` does not.

Comment: @mercury0114 Yes, if you pre-compile a header then you treat it differently from a header which you don't pre-compile. I don't know if that is related to stdafx.h; you should check the documentation of your compiler regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be faster as the precompiled headers (should) already have been run through the pre-processor, compiler flags affecting the code here should also have done its things.

So compared to an include that still needs to do these things it should be faster.

Comment: Does it mean that in this case the header file `stdafx.h` is somehow special and compiler treats it differently than other header files? Because if not, I don't see why `#include <stdafx.h>` gives rise to a "precompiled header" whereas `#include<another_file.h>` does not.